# Output to temporary file and pipe to other process

Tags: bash

I am using a tool `tool_1` which does not support to output to `stdout`, only a file. I want to output to a temporary file (which is created on the spot) and pipe the contents to another tool `tool_2`. Is that possible in bash?

Basically, I want to combine both statements into a single statement, while elegantly creating a temporary file which will be cleaned up afterwards:

```
tool_1 ... > output
tool_2 ... < output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, with some caveats, using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
tool_1 ... >(tool_2 ...)
```

Specify `>(tool_2 ...)` wherever `tool_1` expects a file name.

Process substitution is implemented using pipes in one form or another, so it doesn’t support everything a file supports; notably, it’s not possible to seek in the resulting “file”.

If that’s not appropriate, use a temporary file:

```
file=$(mktemp); tool_1 ... "$file" && < "$file" tool_2 ...; rm "$file"
```